# shared window in blazor ssr

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, signalr

how can I implement a way to render same details for two different user!

assuming I have a one customer that need to give help from our support team to learn about application or solving problems
now I want to have a way to share that entire changes and sync supporter screen and customer and their interactions

Comment: Not possible. Use the standard screen shared techniques, as you would or any other application.

Comment: We are an iranian and in iran theres no good screen sharing device because in our country some applications is banned from iran and anothers banned from owned country!!!

Comment: But i have some ideas for it and dont know which one is working.

Comment: For this kind of technology, capture screen is based on the user client browser, did chrome or edge could be used in your country?

Comment: yes we using chrome and edge